# How to append just before the end of the BODY tag using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I'm having a few problems trying to append some additional HTML at the bottom of the page but within the BODY tag. I can append the HTML at the bottom however it's outside the BODY tag. Can anyone please help me?

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
window.onload=function(){
$('body').after('<div>footer</div>');
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>Page content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The result is:

```
<body>
<div>Page content</div>
</body>
<div>footer</div>
```

But I need it to be:

```
<body>
<div>Page content</div>
<div>footer</div>
</body>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: *"How to append..."* Use `.append` instead of `.after`. I know it's sounds crazy, but it's true!

Comment: Felix! You're a Genius!  It's now working perfectly!  Cheers!